# What's written on the two stones (Possibly in Chinese) in blade runner?

Tags: plot-explanation, blade-runner

After that conversation between Roy and Leon, the camera moves away.
They walk past an area where there are two big stones with writings on it.

What's written on those two stones?

See here:

Comment: Relevant scene: 3:34 to 3:48